# Best setting for record sound

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, avaudioplayer

What's the best settings for the recorder for recording voice?
What should i replace with '?' in below code?

```
recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:?] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:?] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: ?] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:?] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:?] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:?] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```

Comment: you're asking 2 questions. also, please reformat your question to elaborate on 'best' - otherwise, i'll just tell you 96000 Hz, 64 bit signed PCM is more than adequate to store a human voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be a fine starting point for speech, considering the hardware (since this is tagged 'iphone', i am assuming that is the source).

```
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12000.0f] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1 /* mono */ ] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NX_BigEndian == NXHostByteOrder()] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:0] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```

if you want to reduce the size of the file, then you may prefer to record at a higher quality, then convert to a compressed format following record.

if you have long recordings to make, then you may want to record to a compressed format (i'd avoid it otherwise because the resource demands are higher).

as it is, these may not be the best for a specific application, but a good balance between size, speed, and quality.

Comment: Error : undeclared 'NX_BigEndian','kAudioFormatLinearPCM'

Comment: you're missing some `#includes`. `grep -r NX_BigEndian /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk`, and `grep -r kAudioFormatLinearPCM /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk`

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what should i add to my app?

Comment: you include the files that declare these, as returned by the `grep` commands i provided. `grep` is a popular command line utility - i pasted `grep` commands which you enter into a terminal, `grep` then tells you where these patterns are declared in the SDK. the missing includes are: `#include <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>` and `#include <architecture/byte_order.h>`

Comment: Thank you, i use this setting but sound recorded with low quality why?

Comment: you're welcome. there are multiple reasons why it could sound 'low quality', some are implementation defined. 16bit at 12kHz should be fine for voice (as a final delivery format). however, the sample rate conversion in use may not be particularly high quality. you could try increasing the sample rate to `44100.0f` - 16 bit/44.1kHz is CD quality (which is overkill for voice), then reducing the sample rate until you have found a good sample rate for your needs. it may also help to test very high values (e.g., 32 bit @ 48kHz), just so you know the highest quality audio the device is capable of.